# Launch browser through testcafe without test

Tags: cross-browser, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I want to use testcafe to start browsers available through internal end external browser providers. I don't want any testing functionality. But I want to be able to use takeScreenshot, resizeWindow, etc.

Here is my code.

```js
const pool = require("./node_modules/testcafe/lib/browser/provider/pool.js");

pool.getProvider("chrome").then((provider) => {
    const plugin = provider.plugin;

    console.log("open")

    plugin.openBrowser("foo", "http://google.de", "chrome").then(() => {
        console.log("done");

    }).catch(console.warn);;

    console.log("early");

}).catch(console.warn);
```

If I run or debug the file with this code, the open browser promise is never resolved. The console prints `open` and `early` and then the program exits.

If I copy and paste the code into an interactive node shell, the browser gets started. (I get an exception that [connection is null](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/master/src/browser/provider/plugin-host.js#L36) but this code is never run if I start the file.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: This is the code that uses async/await, but does not work either:

```js
const pool = require("../node_modules/testcafe/lib/browser/provider/pool.js");

(async () => {
    const provider = await pool.getProvider("chrome");
    const plugin = provider.plugin;
    await plugin.openBrowser("foo", "http://google.de", "chrome");
    console.log("done");
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

We advise against using this internal API as it can be changed at any time without notification.
You can use the [testcafe-browser-tools](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-browser-tools/blob/master/API.md) module instead.

The [plugin.openBrowser](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/plugin-api/browserprovider.html#openbrowser) method is async. So, you need to await the result of the method execution. Please see TestCafe's `runBrowser` [code](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/8dc3da9a01aca63efbed9a415af690128c6bc1fb/src/browser/connection/index.js#L78) for more details.

Comment: Am I able to start any browser available through third party providers through testcafe-browser-tools? That is the requirement.

Comment: You wrote: "The plugin.openBrowser method is async."
Yes. I just use the Promise returned by the async function instead. I figured that might be easier to understand than an immediatly executed async function. (I tried that first)